# Why is sum of Boltzmann factors equal to $1 + \exp(-\epsilon / k T)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am bit confused about how they write
$$ Z = \sum e^{- \epsilon_i / kT} = 1 + e^{-\epsilon/kT}$$
Where did the subscript $i$ go and where does the $1+e^{-\epsilon/kT}$ come from?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for equations. This site supports mathjax. Please use mathjax for all math equations on this site.

Comment: What is the sum over...? If there are only two $\epsilon_i$'s, namely $0$ and $\epsilon$, then you will get the required result.

Comment: Also what is $\epsilon$?

Comment: Energy of a particular state

Comment: $\epsilon$, not $\epsilon_i$. Ah, I see now that this is the question.

Comment: Who is "they"? While I believe that Tyler and Soba are correct, for completeness it would be useful to quote the source of the claim. If it helps, we do have a short tutorial on [MathJax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for use in writing equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is vaguely posed, the answer is probably that this is a partition function for a two-state system (since the sum has only two elements) with energy states $\epsilon_i=\{0,\epsilon\}$. This then means $$Z=\sum _{i=1}^{2}{e}^{-\epsilon_i /{k}_{B}T}=1+{e}^{-\epsilon/{k}_{B}T}$$